# Upload de arquivos Android

Tags: android, upload, ftp

Fiz uma aplicação onde eu seleciono uma foto do álbum e carrego em um imageView. Agora preciso fazer uma função para fazer o upload dessa mesma imagem para o meu FTP online. Estou vendo n exemplos e nada funciona. Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Insira no em sua pergunta o que já tentou.

Comment: Já tentei muita coisa. Só preciso de uma solução simples

Comment: Seria interessante vc seguir um exemplo e mostrar sua dificuldade em cima deste exemplo. Vc disse q tentou n exemplos.

Comment: Exato não adianta nada continuarmos dando exemplos e você continuar afirmando que não funciona. "Não funciona" é muito vago...